# Multiplying One column with others in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, multiple-columns

hope everything is doing well.

I'm stuck trying to multiply one column with others.

| A | Mult1 | Mult2 | Mult3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 6 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 | 5 |

I want to create a new columns named MultA1, MultA2, MultA3 this way

| MultA1 | MultA2 | MultA3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 6 | 8 | 12 |
| 2 | 8 | 10 |

Is there an easy way to do it for many columns?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dplyr::across` for this:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  A = 1:3,
  Mult1 = 2:4,
  Mult2 = 3:5,
  Mult3 = 4:6
)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Mult"),
                ~ A * .x,
                .names = "{.col}A"))

#>   A Mult1 Mult2 Mult3 Mult1A Mult2A Mult3A
#> 1 1     2     3     4      2      3      4
#> 2 2     3     4     5      6      8     10
#> 3 3     4     5     6     12     15     18
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy `dplyr`approach:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(
    MultA1 = A*Mult1,
    MultA2 = A*Mult2,
    MultA3 = A*Mult3
  ) %>%
  select(-c(1:4))
  MultA1 MultA2 MultA3
1      2      3      4
2      6      8     10
3     12     15     18
```

A `base R` approach with `lapply` is this:

```
df[paste0("MultA", 1:3)] <- lapply(df[2:4], function(x) x*df$A)
df[,1:4] <- NULL                                   # remove the original four columns
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = 1:3,
  Mult1 = 2:4,
  Mult2 = 3:5,
  Mult3 = 4:6
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiply `A` to all the `'Mult'` columns directly.

```
cols <- grep('Mult', names(df), value = TRUE)
df[paste0(cols, 'A')] <- df$A * df[cols]
df

#  A Mult1 Mult2 Mult3 Mult1A Mult2A Mult3A
#1 1     2     3     4      2      3      4
#2 2     3     4     6      6      8     12
#3 2     1     4     5      2      8     10
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 2), Mult1 = c(2, 3, 1), 
                 Mult2 = c(3, 4, 4), Mult3 = c(4, 6, 5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `startsWith` from `base R`

```
i1 <- startsWith(names(df), 'Mult')
df[paste0(names(df)[i1], "A")] <- df[i1] * df$A
```